# How to remove entrypoint from parent Image in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I want to remove entrypoint from Dockerfile, but parent image has an entrypoint.

How can I remove it?

Answer (score 211, accepted):

Per the discussion [here](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/3465#issuecomment-47598629), you should be able to reset the entrypoint with

```
ENTRYPOINT []
```

Comment: Next time you are in Berlin, beers on me! :)

Comment: now, when i run my image, it says: docker: Error response from daemon: No command specified.

Answer (score 43):

When you want to override the entrypoint in the `run` command:

For example if you want to attach and run sh inside the container

```
docker run -it --entrypoint='' my-image sh
```

Answer (score 23):

Put this line in your Dockerfile

`ENTRYPOINT []`

Answer (score 9):

There are two ways to go about it :

1. If you want the override to happen at build time , then create a docker file for child image and specify the new Entrypoint there

   ```
   FROM PARENT_IMAGE
   ENTRYPOINT [new_entry_point]
   ```

2.Another way would be to do the override at the runtime , i.e, by using the `--entrypoint` flag:

```
    docker run --entrypoint=/bin/bash CHILD_IMAGE
```

Comment: Thank you attention, but question is remove it, not change it.

Comment: You can remove it using --entrypoint="" in the run command. Thanks, Rambler!

Answer (score 1):

If you use docker-compose, entrypoint directive will override the one in Dockerfile.

Add this in your docker-compose.yml:

```
entrypoint: /the/entrypoint/I_want.sh
command: first_argument_to_be_executed
```